# How to delete Nhibernate many-to-many association without deleting referenced objects

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many, associations

Good day all

I am having trouble deleting the associations between two objects without deleting the objects in NHibernate. My mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<property name="Name" column="[SiteGroupName]"/>

<many-to-one name="ClientInfo" column="[ClientID]"/>

<set name="internalSites" table="SiteGroupSites" cascade="none" inverse="true">
  <key column="[SiteGroupID]"/>
  <many-to-many class="Site" column="SiteID"/>
</set>

<set name="internalSiteGroups" table="SiteGroupGroups" cascade="none" inverse="true">
  <key column="[SiteGroupID]"/>
  <many-to-many class="SiteGroup" column="ChildSiteGroupID"/>
</set>
```

So in my C# code I Remove a Site from SiteGroup:

```
siteGroup.Sites.Remove(site);
```

What I don't understand is that when I save, it deletes the association and the actual site. Am I misunderstanding something? What I want is for Site to be Removed from SiteGroup, not completely deleted.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem Fouche ?

Answer (score 0):

How about

site.Sitegroup = null;
//Save